# IntelliJ 14 missing HOME env. variable

Tags: intellij-idea, path-variables, intellij-14

Whenever I start IntelliJ I see a notification balloon pointing out that I have an undeclared HOME variable. I can remove it but the same thing happens when I open IntelliJ again. I would like to fix it but I have no idea which HOME variable it is referring to.

The project is a Grails 2.4 project with a JDK7 on Windows 7.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting it to the root of your user account? At least, that's what I'd assume it's talking about.

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. In earlier releases of IntelliJ I don't recall that necessary. I'm gonna try :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set this enviroment variable in your windows system settings?

I think the name of this variable must be `M2_HOME` and must point to the path of your maven installation.

start -> right click on computer -> extended system settings -> enviroment

See also: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi under section "Installation Instructions" and "Windows".